# Azure Pipelines how filter artifacts per stage for "Manual only" triggered Releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Let's say I have these 3 Stages: Dev, QC, Prod.

My requirements are:

1. Artifacts only from specific branches(release/*)  can be deployed to QC/Prod
2. Artifacts from all branches can be deployed to Dev

I can achieve what I want using **Artifact filters** for "After stage" triggered Releases but I need this for "Manual only".

Is there a workaround that will let me control/filter which artifacts are available for deployment for specific stages/environments?

[image]

Basically, I need the Azure DevOps equivalent of [Octopus Channels](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/channels).

**Update**
I think I'm close to a solution.
In the "Pre-deployment conditions", I can add a new Deployment Gate which makes a Rest API call.
e.g `URL suffix=/Release/releases/76`

Now, I just need to correctly parse the ApiResponse because the below Success criteria doesn't work

```
eq(root['artifacts[0].definitionReference.branch.id'], 'refs/heads/master')
```

> Evaluation of expression 'eq(root['artifacts[0].definitionReference.branch.id'], 'refs/heads/master')' failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you can do this using Deployment gates on your stages.

1. Create a new Generic service connection from Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Service Connections.
   For service URL something like `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis`
2. On your stage, open the Pre-Deployment Conditions
3. Enable the Gates option.
4. Add a new Invoke REST API gate  and set the Delay before evaluation to 0 minutes.
   4.1 Set the connection type to Generic.
   4.2 Select the service connection you created in step 1.
   4.3 Set the method to GET.
   4.4 Set the URL suffix to `/Release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)`
   4.5 On the Advanced area, set the Completion Event to ApiResponse.
   4.6 On the Advanced area, set the success criteria to (or startsWith)
   `eq(root['artifacts'][0]['definitionReference']['branch']['id'],'refs/heads/master')`

Now, if you try to deploy an artifact not from the master branch, the deployment will fail

Comment: I used a Personal Access Token to authenticate my request with login/password. But they have a limited time span of max 1 year. Is there a more integrated or permanent solution to query the same organization API from the release gates ?

Comment: hi, this allowed me to solve my issue, only problem was even with a full access pat token the _apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId) keeps giving me a page not found but I managed it another way with /build/builds/$(Build.BuildId) and then eq(root['sourceBranch'],'refs/heads/master'). No idea why the release url won't work as appears correct according to MS docs

Comment: my apologies missed the vsrm, build urls work without it but release urls require it, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

In the QC/Prod stages add a custom condition that the job will be executed only where the artifacts source branch is `release/*`:

```
startsWith(variables['Release.Artifacts.{Artifacts-Alias}.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')
```

[image]

Now, when you manually run the QC/Prod stages and the artifacts not came from the release the job not will be executed:

[image]

Comment: Shayki, thanks for the answer. I read about this after  I posted the question. I'll try this today

Comment: I misunderstood your answer, if possible, I'd prefer not to run the job at all.
I think I can achieve that using deployment gates, see my update

Comment: Oh ok, a good idea also, but the expression docs so poor, I don't know how to get it work :(

Comment: You are right, I outsourced this to my brother and he found the solution. Your approach could help on other scenarios though +1

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
and(contains(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'), succeeded())
```